# Typescript object initialisation with variable same key and value got type error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I have an object `components` like this

```
const a = Text;  // A component 
const b = Button; // A component
const components = {
   a: a,
   b: b
  }
```

I use ES6 feature and remove repetition as

```
const components = {
       a,
       b
    }
```

when I use components as `components['a']` I got some type of error

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because of expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type 'Element'.

Comment: Interesting. Whats the type of `component` in both cases?

Comment: Seems to work, coudl you provide  sample code to reproduce ? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=1#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgIYILwIBIBUCyAZAEQEsA3AUQBsBTAWyqjgG4EEB6VhAQQUhoAcI9OKEixEAIzSZceAEIBXOHGiVaQ5uy48I-aEJHR423VCEwATFIDeoFkgA0thONABfUAZNnzAbQDkSH4AukA